# How to add value in SQL?

Tags: mysql

Good Day Experts,

I want to find out how can update records in a particular table where it will still retain the same value and then add a certain value..

for example

```
database: product, table stoklist. 
         id    stock
         1     150
         2     100
```

my goal is, when I update the the Stock, let say I add 50 on its value, i want to add the figure i enter and then add it to the remaining no. of stock..

I hope you will help me with my problem.

I'm planning to create inventory syste, in PHP MySQL.

Comment: I believe you can do UPDATE tablename SET stock = stock + 50 WHERE id =1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE stoklist SET stock = stock + 50 WHERE id = 1;
```

This would add 50 to the stock corresponding to the id 1.